# Difference between quoted strings and non quoted single words in CSV file

Tags: magento2, csv

Can anyone explain why in some CSV's translations are not always in " ".

For example in the tax csv:

Tax,Tax

Shouldn't it be:

"Tax","Tax"

Answer (score 1):

For translation containing one word you can write without quotes but both works.
If your translation contains many words you have to put them in quotes.

Exemple :

```
 Tax,Tax
 "Subtotal","Subtotal"
 "Gift Card","Gift Card"
```